# Get the length of items in ng-repeat outside the loop in Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML where i am listing few items with Angular JS **ng-repeat**

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-list" data-ng-repeat="details in response.data" data-ng-show='$index<3'>{{ details.name }}</div>
    <div class="show-more" data-ng-if="details.length > 3"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

`header-list` and `show-more` are sibling **div**s and i have ng-repeat on `header-list`. i only want to show the div `show-more` if the number of items in `header-list` is more than 3. since the scope of the ng-repeat is not in `show-more` i cannot do this. is there a way to do this without changing the DOM structure? Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand right... u need that "show-more" div to display multiple times... meaning for each element "details" where the property length > 3 without being rendered by the ng-repeat which stays on the "header-list" div. If this is the problem, I don't think you will have a normal, straight forward solution.

Comment: @DA Not really. Sorry for the confusion. i have updated the question and and hope its clear now

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
<div class="header-list" data-ng-repeat="details in response.data | limitTo: 3">{{ details.name }}</div> 
<div class="show-more" data-ng-if="response.data.length > 3">View All</div>
```